# Dependency Injection with parameterized constructor

Tags: angular

I'm working around the dependency injection in angular 2.
I had written a sample service which will not contain any constructor
My service :

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'

@Injectable()
export class MyFirstServiceClass{
  //Not working with parameter
  // constructor(nm:string){   
  // }
  SayHello(){
    alert();
      return "Hello, I'm Service...";
  }
}
```

I accessed the service via dependency injection from the constructor as follows :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MyFirstServiceClass} from './MyFirstService.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  Assignonclick : string;
  constructor(public refsrvc : MyFirstServiceClass){
   this.title = refsrvc.SayHello();
  }
 CallServiceOnBtnClick(){
  this.Assignonclick = this.refsrvc.SayHello();
 }

}
```

It's working if I didnt provide a parameter to the constructor of my service class.
In case I do the following as like providing the parameter in the constructor, I was not able to perform DI.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyFirstServiceClass{
  //Not working with parameter
  constructor(nm:string){   
  }
  SayHello(){
    alert();
      return "Hello, I'm Service...";
  }
}
```

This is providing me the following image straight forward error :

[image]
How can I perform DI with parameter ?

Comment: Why are you passing the string to the constructor? Why can't you use another method to act as getter/setter

Comment: It's like assumption as like IF it expects a parameter : Then how to handle DI?

Answer (score 2):

Because you want DI mechanism to create for you the instance of `MyFirstServiceClass` - DI mechanism must know anything about the constructor parameters of that injectable service.

When you do this

```
constructor(public refsrvc : MyFirstServiceClass){

}
```

DI knows that there is something to inject with type `MyFirstServiceClass`, so it tries to inject it. But when it tries access the constructor of that class -
at that moment DI knows nothing about parameter `nm:string` so why it can't create an instance of the `MyFirstServiceClass`. So based on the type of your parameter which is `string` it gives you correct error

> No Provider for String

Comment: That's fine, But How can I handle this situation ?

Comment: This is related to your issue. If you want to pass just simple string into your constructor, maybe constructor is not the correct place?

Comment: But, In general what our DI says is that "even it(service) modify.. We can easily access without any interruption". Am I wrong ?

Comment: You can also mark the parameter with `@Optional`, this will let your code pass

Comment: If I provide @Optional, Then I can create directly an instance. Then whats the need of Dependency Injection ?

Comment: The needs of DI after making Optional does not change. That does not mean that you need to create the instance directly. Of course every time you can do that and it is not relate to the Optional

Answer (score 0):

Your service:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyFirstServiceClass{
  nm: string;

  constructor(nm:string){
    this.nm = nm;
  }
  SayHello(){
    alert();
      return "Hello, I'm Service...";
  }
}
```

When you want to use it:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MyFirstServiceClass} from './MyFirstService.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  refsrvc : MyFirstServiceClass
  Assignonclick : string;

  constructor() {
    this.refsrvc = new MyFirstServiceClass('The string of the constructor');
    this.title = this.refsrvc.SayHello();
  }

  CallServiceOnBtnClick(){
    this.Assignonclick = this.refsrvc.SayHello();
  }
}
```

Comment: For doing DI in a proper way check @Suren Srapyan answer ;)

Comment: Sorry, If my question is wrong. I don't understand, If our provider is not able to catch or create instance without parameters,  Then what is the use of DI ? Directly I can go ahead with your answer right ?

Comment: Because DI trusts in the principle that you don't need to know anything about the service you are injecting (basically you don't need to know if your service requires a determined string or other kind of value to be created) Check this section of the manual, the explanation is quite reasonable. https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-pattern. And yes, my answer should allow you to use the service ;)

Comment: Yes, That's the main plot or guide where I registered this doubt.  If you observe in the guide you mentioned, we can see a statement like "What if the Engine class evolves and its constructor requires a parameter? That would break the Car class and it would stay broken until you rewrote it along the lines of this.engine = new Engine(theNewParameter). "   This was the same I was asking. But they gave as this can be resolved in DI.

Comment: But in the guide they are talking about building a class and use a service to do it, in your case you are building the service with params, doing this the DI doesn't know what the constructor needs. Imagine your string needs to have a specific value, how would the DI know which value is the correct one?

Comment: Yes @Talavera , That's the point I missed. Then whats the service there among car, tier and engine. Thanks for it. And finally in the same guide I found "injector.get(Car);" To get injector, what we need to import ? I tried with injectable from angular/core. But not getting.

Comment: Hi, import { Injector } from '@angular/core'; If it works mar the question as solved to help others ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass parameter or either use get/set, if you have defined parameter in the constructor class of the service.